# AngularJS - Which is good WCF Rest or Web API

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I'm going to start a new AngularJS Project blended with Microsoft .NET. **Now I'm confused which one should I select, WCF Rest or Web API ?**

My Angular App has a Login Module and a Main Application. Only the authenticated user can access the Main Application. In Web API we have to use Token System or Owin Auth, but some blogs are saying its not so secure. So, I am totally confused which should I choose ? which one is efficient and secure ?

**WCF Rest**

1. To use WCF as WCF Rest service we have to enable `webHttpBindings`.
2. It supports HTTP GET and POST verbs by `[WebGet]` and `[WebInvoke]`
   attributes respectively.
3. To enable other HTTP verbs we have to do some configuration in IIS
   to accept request of that particular verb on .svc files
4. Passing data through parameters using a `WebGet` needs configuration.
   The `UriTemplate` must be specified
5. It supports XML, JSON and ATOM data format.

**Web API**

1. This is the new framework for building HTTP services with easy and
   simple way.
2. Web API is open source, an ideal platform for building REST-ful
   services over the .NET Framework.
3. Unlike WCF Rest service, it uses the full features of HTTP (like URIs,
   request/response headers, caching, versioning, various content
   formats)
4. It also supports the MVC features such as routing, controllers,
   action results, filter, model binders, IOC container or dependency
   injection, unit testing that makes it more simple and robust.
5. It can be hosted with in the application or on IIS.
6. It is light weight architecture and good for devices which have
   limited bandwidth like smart phones.
7. Responses are formatted by Web API’s `MediaTypeFormatter` into JSON,
   XML or whatever format you want to add as a `MediaTypeFormatter`.

Kindly assist me, which one is efficient and secure?

Comment: one thing i liked when using wcf is the flexibility it offers to support both soap and http services

Comment: `Supports building services with WS-* standards like Reliable Messaging,  Transactions, Message Security.` from this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx WCF is more secure but it also depends on how you implement it

Comment: @IRPunch Use WCF to create reliable, secure web services that accessible over a variety of transports. Use ASP.NET Web API to create HTTP-based services that are accessible from a wide variety of clients.

Comment: https://blog.tonysneed.com/2016/01/06/wcf-is-dead-long-live-mvc-6/

Answer (score 0):

**[Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/)**

1. Lighter-weight than either web-api or WCF
2. Convention-based, low on ceremony
3. As fully featured as WebAPI in terms of HTTP support
4. Supports Razor view engine
5. Supports OWIN pipeline
6. Comes with its own IOC out of the box