# $http AngularJs Services / WCF

Tags: angularjs, wcf, http, service

I'm working with angularJs and I've planned to use angularJs $http services to fetch data from the database. Currently I'm thinking of using WCF to respond to angularjs $http services call. Can anyone please suggest whether using WCF is a favourable option for this purpose / does there exists an alternative to using WCF?

Comment: though WCF supports http but I think using Asp.Net Web Api is a better option because it is improved for http based services and has got all features related to http. Plus you get better control and lesser configurations.

Comment: I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472910/angularjs-which-is-good-wcf-rest-or-web-api) it might help. (Web api vs WCF in Angular)